# точный и текущий

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Являются ли прилагательные *точный* и *текущий* этимологически однокоренными исходя из того, что точными могут быть только текущие (свежие), а не архивные (стоялые) данные?

Answer (score 2):

Нет, так как у них разные корни.
Точный, согласно Викисловарю (который ссылается на другие словарные источники) происходит от праславянского *tъčьka, связано с *tъknǫti (ткать, ткнуть)

Тогда как текущий происходит от праславянского *tekti (двигаться, бежать)

Comment: а точный выстрел, это выстрел в точку? (сердце мишени)

Comment: @prostorech, именно.

Comment: а существительное точка, глагол точить (течь) и прилагательное текущий разве не взаимосвязаны?

Comment: Тут две разные основы. Точить и течь - однокоренные, и производное от них текущий. А точка и точный - другая основа

Comment: Необходимо также помнить, что точка в значении, связанном с "точить" является однокоренной к словам "точить" и "течь": например, точка ножей